# Forward pass neural network output values always converge to a mean

Tags: neural-network

I thought the best way to learn neural networks would be to create one from scratch in JavaScript using the MNIST database of images, each image displaying a single handwritten number from 0 to 9. Each image is 784 pixels, each pixel value being either 1 (white) or 0 (black).

Now before I start posting any code, I wanted to first keep things abstract and talk out my problem to see if I'm just missing something very basic and embarrassing.

NN basic specs are:

- 784 input values 2 hidden layers
- each containing 50 neurons 10
  output neurons representing labels 0 to 9
- beta = 0 in every layer
- learning rate = 0.01 initial weights set using xavier
- activation function = sigmoid throughout for now

When I run this NN over a 1000 images or so, all the outputs slowly descend to around 0.1 and then basically all hover there forever. When I watch a single image flow through the NN and then backprop, this actually makes sense. Most of the time, in fact 90% of the time, the true value for a single output will be zero. Therefore, for a single output, if I run 10 images through, 9 of those images will want the output to move towards truth=zero, while only 1 images will want it to move up to truth=one. I actually see happen in the numbers....you can see a single output value slowly descend towards truth=zero a bunch of times, then get a temporary bump up when truth=one.

I hope this makes sense....basically my NN would rather reduce my total error by moving all my outputs closer to truth=zero. It's almost as if I need to adjust my learning rate to be 10x greater when adjusting my weights towards truth=one...but then I suspect this would just adjust all my outputs to 0.5.

I've been through my code so many times, and I believe my math is good, but of course I could be missing something. That said...I thought I'd start here first and see if anyone else has seen this.

EDIT....raw code containing NN classes. Sorry, bit messy. Basically you call a new network class, then run network.addlayer to populate layers, neurons, and set weights. From there you can start training by call network.inputTrainingData, which accepts the binary array of 784 pixels, and the truth value for the image. And finally, you can network backPropogate after every image.

```js
    class network {

    layers = [];
    learning_rate = 0.01;
    inputCnt = 784;
    labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    xValues = [];
    truth = [];

    constructor() {     

    }

    addLayer(neuronCnt, isOutputLayer) {
        //note...we're not adding an "input layer....why do that when you can just feed the inputs into the first hidden layer?

        if (isOutputLayer) {
            this.layers.push(new layer(this.labels.length, this.layers[this.layers.length - 1].neurons.length, isOutputLayer));
        } else if(this.layers.length) {
            this.layers.push(new layer(neuronCnt, this.layers[this.layers.length - 1].neurons.length, isOutputLayer));
        } else {            
            this.layers.push(new layer(neuronCnt, this.inputCnt, isOutputLayer));
        }        
    }


    get numberOfLayers() {
        return this.layers.length;
    }


    inputTrainingData(data, truth) {
        this.xValues = data;
        this.xValues.forEach(function (x, i) {
            if (x == 0) { x = 0.0001; };
        })
        this.truth = truth;
        var $this = this;
        this.layers.forEach(function (layer, index) {
            layer.input($this.xValues);
            $this.xValues = layer.output();
        });    
    }

    backPropogate() {         
        var $this = this;
        var prev_layer = 0;
        var t = this.getTruth();
        for (var i = this.layers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {            
            this.layers[i].backPropogate(t, $this.learning_rate, prev_layer);
            prev_layer = this.layers[i];
        }
    }

    getTruth() {
        var truth = [];   
        var $this = this;
        this.labels.forEach(function (label, index) {
            if ($this.truth == label) {
                truth.push(1);
            } else {
                truth.push(0);
            }
        })
        return truth;
    }

    }

    class layer {

    neurons = [];
    inputs = [];
    outputs = [];
    final_deriv = [];
    hidden_deriv = [];
    beta = 0; //Math.random();
    isOutputLayer = false;

    constructor(neuronCnt, prevLayerNeuronCnt, _isOutputLayer) {
        this.isOutputLayer = _isOutputLayer;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < neuronCnt; i++) {
            var newNeuron = new neuron(neuronCnt, prevLayerNeuronCnt);
            this.neurons.push(newNeuron);
        }
    }

    input(xValues) {
        this.inputs = xValues;
        var $this = this;
        this.neurons.forEach(function (neuron, index) {
            neuron.input(xValues, $this.beta);
        });
    }

    output() {
        this.outputs = [];
        var $this = this;
        this.neurons.forEach(function (neuron, index) {
            $this.outputs.push(neuron.output($this.isOutputLayer));
        })
        return this.outputs;
    }

    backPropogate(truth, learning_rate, prev_layer) {
        var $this = this;
        this.neurons.forEach(function (neuron, index) {
            neuron.backPropogateWeights(truth[index], learning_rate, prev_layer, index);
            //neuron.backPropogateBeta(truth[index], prev_layer); 
        });

    }
    }

    class neuron {

    xValues = 0;
    b = 0;
    weights = [];
    h = 0;
    neuron_deriv = 1;
    weights_deriv = [];


    constructor(neuronCnt, prevLayerNeuronCnt) {
        var i;
        var xavier = 1 / prevLayerNeuronCnt;        
        for (i = 0; i < prevLayerNeuronCnt; i++) {  
            var rnd = (Math.random() - 0.5) * xavier;
            //rnd = ((Math.random() * 2) - 1) * xavier;
            this.weights.push(rnd);
        }   
    }

    input(xValues, beta) {
        this.xValues = xValues;
        this.b = beta;
    }

    output(isOutputLayer) {
        var func = 0;
        var $this = this;
        this.xValues.forEach(function (x, index) {
            func += x * $this.weights[index];
        });
        func += this.b;

            var sigmoid = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-func));

            $this.h = sigmoid;
            $this.neuron_deriv = (sigmoid * (1 - sigmoid));    


        return this.h;

    }

    backPropogateWeights(truth, learning_rate, prev_layer, cnt) {

        var $this = this;  
        var prevSumError = 1;
        if (prev_layer == 0) {
            //var SqError = Math.pow((this.h - truth), 2)/2;
            var dEdH = (this.h - truth);
            this.neuron_deriv = this.neuron_deriv * dEdH;
        } else {
            prevSumError = 0;
            prev_layer.neurons.forEach(function (neuron, index) {
                prevSumError += neuron.weights_deriv[cnt];
            });
        }

        this.weights.forEach(function (weight, index) {
            $this.weights_deriv.push($this.neuron_deriv * weight * prevSumError);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
            var slope = $this.neuron_deriv * $this.xValues[i] * prevSumError;
            var weightAdjust = learning_rate * slope;
            $this.weights[i] = $this.weights[i] - weightAdjust; 
        }   


    }





    }
```

Comment: You said "before I start posting any code," then went on to describe your problem and didn't post any code. I would post your code if you want to give other people the best chance possible to help you.

Comment: oh sorry....I meant to say that I want to talk this out abstractly without code first...but that I'm happy to add code if this approach doesn't work. I guess I'm just hoping someone else will see that and say "Ah ha!...classic xxxx problem!" But maybe I'm being naive.

Comment: You're fine, and I understand that it's good to try and describe your problem space. However, why share just part of the information you have instead of all of it? It seems like you're trying to abstractly describe your solution and get feedback on it, instead of abstractly describing the problem and sharing your solution for feedback. Reminds me of the xy problem

Comment: okay, code added. wasn't as bad I I though. That said, code is a pure copy/paste, so  hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag

Comment: language tag added

Comment: Just ran the same image a few hundred times, and it successfully converges to the correct label.

Comment: Just ran two images a few hundred times, and the two associated labels do converge, but only as high as 0.55 (truth=1) while every other label drops close to zero (truth=0). I should also note that these two correct labels are not independently hitting 0.55 while the other drops.....instead both labels hit 0.55 together regardless which image is run.

Answer (score 1):

This took a very long time to debug. It was the weights. I was using an xavier function to randomize all the weights, but when I opened up the weight range between -2.5 to 2.5, everything just started worked.

Here was my debug process if it helps anyone else:
 - Repeated all my code calculations by hand to ensure code was running correctly
 - Reduced entire neural network to bare minimal number of layers and neurons.
 - Trained on a single image, then two, then three.
 - First breakthrough was when I trained on just two images and eliminated ALL hidden layer....it actually learned!
 - From here I slowly added in a layer and a few more images.
 - It's at this point I started to expand my weight range....and I could see it was starting to learn.
 - Finally I blew out my weight range, went back to my original setup, and boom! worked!

It's still not learning as fast I it should, based on the same implementation by Andrej Kaparthy in his ConvNetJS....but at least I'm now in a position to start tweaking.